# Is it possible to define pytest "test suites" (with different addopts)?

Tags: pytest

For development, I usually want to execute just a few tests and barely any plugins. For CI/CD, I want to run the whole test suite.

Is there a possibility to add custom commands, e.g.

```
pytest ci: Run all plugins and tests
pytest fast: A couple of plugins which are fast and '-m "not slow"'
pytest bare: No plugins
```

Right now, I have `addopts` in `setup.cfg` with all the plugins. I have no idea how to overwrite this to not add the plugins. Is that possible?

The best option I found so far is to define those as targets in a Makefile. I would prefer if there is an option directly in pytest.